# HighCharts - How can I turn off the DX lines?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using HighCharts.https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.dmi is the documentation. I would like to turn off dx line but at first I do not know how is that called. Therefore I can not turn them off. how am I able to stop showing that line? i only need plus di (green) and minus di (red) line only. [image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample code for drawing this component? Preferably with the data you are transmitting

Comment: here it is https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/indicators/dmi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hide()` method on this line's graph to achieve this, but then I think you'd have to disable the display of the tooltip for that particular series because it positions it based on that series and will still contain *DX* information. If you would like to display information about *+DI* and *-DI* values, then you should set custom tooltip formatting to display these values when hovering over other series ([`tooltip.formatter()`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.formatter))

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            render: function() {
                const chart = this;
                
                console.log(chart.series[1].graph.hide());
            }
        }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        id: 'aapl',
        data: data
    }, {
        type: 'dmi',
        linkedTo: 'aapl',
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }]
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zf1Lypsc/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.enableMouseTracking